# What is a better way to calculate bitmap series?

Tags: python, bitmap, mapreduce, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a situation where I need to calculate bitmap over a long range. I don't want to go over too much details about the problem statement because it is not important. I rather simplify the problem for better understanding. I have some pseudo code below in python:

```
n1=12000
while n > 0:
   if a == 1:
      bitmap_of_n1 = (bitmap_of_n1 << 1)+1 #add a 1 to bitmap
   else:
      bitmap_of_n1 = bitmap_of_n1 << 1 #add a zero to bitmap
   n1 -= 1

n2=12000
while n > 0:
   if a == 1:
      bitmap_of_n2 = (bitmap_of_n2 << 1)+1 #add a 1 to bitmap
   else:
      bitmap_of_n2 = bitmap_of_n2 << 1 #add a zero to bitmap
   n2 -= 1
 #....n100 or so
```

Of course I don't do it in sequence. I utilize MapReduce to do this calculation, but my main question is that if my bitmap "building" (using bitwise shifting) is efficient, or is there a better way to do this? I'm using leftmost bit as start and newer bit is lower-order bit. What if I want to use rightmost bit as start and newer bit is "bigger" bit, how could I do it and is it more efficient than what I did above?

I need bitmap of each block (n1,n2...,n100) to be the same length and perfectly aligned (by this I mean the first bit of n1 should XOR with first bit of n2, and so on). I will do XOR between blocks at the later steps.

Greatly appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't really understand the reasoning behind this, particularly not using MapReduce for this. Maybe I missed something, but as far as I can tell it's completely trivial - you either shift left by `n` while appending zeroes, or you shift left by `n` while appending ones (which is just `(x + 1) << n - 1`). I see no reason to do either of them bit-by-bit.

Comment: @harold in my problem, n is not unknown beforehand, but I know it's just really big. I represent n=[arbitrary number] in the above example to illustrate that it's big and I will need to do A Lot of bit shifting. Basically, the idea is for every round of while loop, I will need to build a bit. My end result will be a bunch of bits and I can represent it has hex or whatever. Hope it clears thing up, else please let me know if you have other doubts

Comment: So `n` changes during the loop?

Comment: do you mean 'a'? n just represents how long the loop will run. 'a' value does change during loop, that's why I need to do bit-by-bit

Comment: @harold I just updated the question, and think it's more accurate of what I'm asking. Copy it here: I'm using leftmost bit as start and newer bit is lower-order bit. What if I want to use rightmost bit as start and newer bit is "bigger" bit, how could I do it and is it more efficient than what I did above?

Comment: Ok well, a problem here is that you've thrown away all of the structure of the problem. The way you've described it, there is no opportunity to do it in a significantly different way (apart from reassociation, because it doesn't matter which order the bits are produced in as long as they end up in the right place eventually)

Comment: Thanks @Harold. Because somebody suggested me that I should use my start bit as the rightmost bit and put newer as higher-based bit instead of building bitmap starting at leftmost bit. I think the bit shifting in my calculation might be wrong or inefficient, that's why I want to ask if I can somehow build bitmap starting from the rightmost bit (maybe don't use bit shifting)

Comment: and yes, it's hard to bring the whole problem up here to explain, but what I have to do is pretty much the same. I will have to read in a very large file line by line, at each line, I will check the ID and status. The file is sorted by ID (ID could be repeated in multiple lines). I have to calculate bitmap for each ID block (contain multiple rows) based on status. Hope it makes sense